# Cerrar una aplicacion en android

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Estoy realizando una aplicación en android, y llegado a un activity quiero que cuando el usuario pulse la tecla volver hacia atras no vaya a la pantalla anterior sino que vuelva al menu inicial del movil.

La aplicacion sería así: al entrar en la aplicacion entro en la activity A, de esa pasaría al activity B y posteriormente al C o D.
Pero si desde C o D vuelvo hacia atras quiero que vaya directamente al inicio del movil y que la aplicacion se quede en la backStack.
Menu Inicio->A->B->C o D
No quiero que la pantalla desde D vuelva a A y ahí salga. Eso se puede hacer??

En definitiva la pregunta es como se puede salir de una aplicacion desde cualquier activity y que esta se quede en el backStack.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes hacer uso del método sobre escrito onBackPressed(). Lo puedes importar y puedes recibir más información [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el metodo **onBackPressed**, dentro del metodo puedes anexar las acciones que quieres que realize tu aplicación.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

También puedes usar el metodo **onKeyDown**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //return true;
           //agregas la logica/acciones a realizar
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la info :)